# Python multiple assignment: want to (tokens.append(),tokens.append(), remaining) = remaining.partition(blank)

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I would like to do:

```
    (tokens.append(),tokens.append(), remaining) = remaining.partition(blank)
```

but that is not valid syntax. Instead, I do:

```
    (t1, t2, remaining) = remaining.partition(blank) 
    tokens.append(t1) 
    tokens.append(t2)
```

Is there a cleaner way? 
BTW I believe I must use .partition, because I must not collapse multiple blanks into one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tokens.extend(remaining.partition(blank))
remaining = tokens.pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you can accomplish this with [extended iterable unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
*tokens[len(tokens):], remaining = remaining.partition(' ')
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Good to know for when I get there.

Answer (score 0):

## My goal was to get each of the {individual elements of a result} to be delivered as either a parameter to a method or as a value to an assignment.

remaining = 'abc def ghi jkl'
tokens=[]

## I would like to, conceptually

## (tokens.append(),tokens.append(), remaining) = remaining.partition(blank)

## Alternative 1: This is what I did:

(t1, t2, remaining) = remaining.partition(blank)

tokens.append(t1)

tokens.append(t2)

## Alternative 2: Very ugly, due to unnecessary repetitive processing of the "heavy lifting," which in this case, was the partitioning:

[(tokens.append(t1), tokens.append(t2), remaining) for t1 in (remaining.partition(' ')[0],) for t2 in (remaining.partition(' ')[1],) for remaining in (remaining.partition(' ')[2],) ]

## Alternative 3: Still ugly, but conceptually closer:

t=remaining.partition(' ')

[(tokens.append(t1), tokens.append(t2), remaining) for t1 in (t[0],) for t2 in (t[1],) for remaining in (t[2],) ]

## The tricks here are to use method invocations before the "for's" and single item lists for the "in's." The comma in single item lists, such as, (t[0],) must follow the only item. The comma may not preceed it.